# [Fixed]Nexus 5 displaying static screen

Tags: nexus-5, screen

I am using Nexus 5 for at least a year. Suddenly the screen went crazy and it started turning off and on again. I tried to turn it on, but it didn't work, the screen was black. After a while, I could turn it on, but the screen was displaying static noise like this (not my phone):

[image: not my phone]

I had my phone with USB debug mode enabled and used [this Java application](http://en.miui.com/thread-57263-1-1.html) to mirror my phone screen. There was no problem using my phone from my PC, but the screen still was static. The touchscreen is working, but I asked a tech guy and he suggested to change the display. I bought the part and replaced it myself, but it didn't work (same results).

Now I've been researching a little more and I found out that the problem could be the charging port mic flex connection to the display. Can someone answer me if they have faced this same issue before and how they fixed it?

Fix:
It seems the flex connector (see image) was damaged by water,
[image: Nexus 5 Display Flex Connector]
 I replaced it and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem after **updating Android OS to 5.0**

**The scenario was**:
I updated the Android OS to 5.0 and within some days my phone automatically **shut down** and also the **screen gone OFF** some times automatically.

As my phone was under warranty period , so i went to service center and they change charging port and reset Android OS to 4.4 .

Now again I updated Android OS to 5.0

But after few hours same problem occur, again went to service center and this time they change motherboard. But after few days problem again occur again and this time they change motherboard again, charger and USB Cable and they also suggested to not use other companies USB cables instead of original.

Now 3 months are passed and there is no sign of problem and I am using it on system on debug mode too, but avoid to use other USB cables. 
(**Note**: 2 times my screen gone OFF in between - I long pressed again and again on Power button then it gone shutdown and I restarted phone again to work perfect)

So I guess information may help you and you can go for the same.

Thanks and best of luck for your device.

Comment: You could simply say "**Visit Service Center**"  in your Answer! Anyways, that is probably not Questioner want to hear on this site, I guess